# Totally corrupted Android Studio project

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

I'm very new to all this. I've been working on a very simple (<10 lines of code) project in kotlin. I got the whole thing running (finally) but realized that it was a debug build. So It changed the build type to release and tried to rebuild. Several bad things happened:

1 - Build said Error in IDE
2 - Unable to find Gradle tasks to build [].
3 - A couple of times there was a java trace back with a button to report, which I did
4 - Trying to choose a new build variate no gives: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ClipApplication\settings.gradle.kts:7:21: Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
5 - Tried to resync Gradle. Got:
e: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\ClipApplication\settings.gradle.kts:7:9: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public abstract fun maven(p0: Closure<(raw) Any!>!): MavenArtifactRepository! defined in org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler
public abstract fun maven(p0: Action<in MavenArtifactRepository!>!): MavenArtifactRepository! defined in org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler

Being new to this, I now have a completely trashed project and no clue about what's wrong and therefore, no clue about how to fix it.

Some help would really be appreciated.

I have invalidated the caches and restart several times.
I have tried deleting the .gradle and .idea folders.

Comment: Drop your gradle configuration files here for more understanding of the problem.